# Didn't load into grub after installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Having some issues after installing Kubuntu 18.04, didn't load into grub after installation, already tried boot repair but got an error "The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode". Here's a paste bin from boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bTPMvkDQXQ/ 
Anyone know the problem? 
UPDATE: Can't use boot repair without internet connection error, how do I get around this?

Comment: You only have gpt partitioned drives. Windows only boots in UEFI boot mode from gpt. So best to have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. So the directions from Boot-Repair say you should reboot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode and then run Boot-Repair to install the UEFI version of grub. What brand/model system? You may have to turn on allow UEFI boot from USB on many systems in UEFI/BIOS settings. You do not need /boot partition with most desktop installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: So /boot is pointless correct? And what do you mean by system?  The Mobo I have is an asrock extreme 3.

Comment: If your system uses UEFI then the system disk must use the GPT partition scheme, both Windows and Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode, and in Ubuntu you must have an EFI system partition mounted on `/boot/efi`. If your system uses BIOS then the system disk must use the MBR partition scheme, and both Windows and Ubuntu must be installed in legacy mode. In both situations you may or may not use a dedicated `/boot` partition in Ubuntu, depending on other considerations.

Comment: Many Asrock  motherboards have issues with the Asmedia ports. Make sure you are not using any of those, not even for a DVD drive. Is this motherboard AMD or Intel?

Comment: The mobo is an intel board and currently don't have the usb drive plugged into any Asmedia ports.

Comment: UPDATE: Booted from the usb in UEFI mode, tried Boot repair but currently getting an error such as  the internet connection being offline.

Comment: How can I use boot repair without internet connection? Already booted from a usb drive but I keep getting the same internet connection error even though i'm online.